# Unresolved Identifier (variable) in different IBActions

Tags: swift, macos

So, I was creating a converting app and I needed to use 2 IBActions.
In one of them I made a constant and I tried to use it in the next one.
But it doesn't work. How can I share the constant?

I am running Xcode 11. I have tried converting it into a variable but no success.

```swift
@IBAction func select(_ sender: Any) {
    let foo = "/some/cool/path.txt"
}

@IBAction func convert(_ sender: Any) {
    let contents = try NSString(contentsOfFile: foo, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) // And here comes the error
}
```

I wanted to use the `foo` constant in other IBAction but I am getting the `Unresolved Identifier "foo"`.

Comment: Declare it outside the function, that is at the class level. I recommend reading https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule: All variables are only visible within the pair of braces they are declared in.

Declare the variable one level higher, and don't use `NSString` in Swift

```
var foo = ""

@IBAction func select(_ sender: Any) {
    foo = "/some/cool/path.txt"
}

@IBAction func convert(_ sender: Any) {
    do {
        let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: foo, encoding: .utf8)
    } catch { print(error) } 
}
```